# How to write stdout to file with colors?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, stdout

A lot of times (not always) the stdout is displayed in colors. Normally I keep every output log in a different file too. Naturally in the file, the colors are not displayed anymore.

[image: Console color output example]

I'd like to know if there's a way (in Linux) to write the output to a file with colors. I'm trying to use `tee` to write the output of vagrant to a file, this way I can still see the output (when it applies). I want to use it specifically for vagrant (it may change in the future, of course...)

Comment: Usually the program doing the writing determines whether it's writing to a terminal, and if it's not it won't use colours. So it's probably a matter of telling the program in question to use colours anyway. Some programs have something like `--color always`, but there's no standard.

Answer (score 66):

Since many programs will only output color sequences if their stdout is a terminal, a general solution to this problem requires tricking them into believing that the pipe they write to is a terminal. This is possible with the `script` command from bsdutils:

```
script -q -c "vagrant up" filename.txt
```

This will write the output from `vagrant up` to filename.txt (and the terminal). If echoing is not desirable,

```
script -q -c "vagrant up" filename > /dev/null
```

will write it only to the file.

Comment: I really like this answer and it's the best one so far, but isn't this a little overkilled? :)

Comment: `script` is surprisingly light, actually. Mostly it just opens a pty, spawns a shell and pipes the output to you. It's some 500 lines of C code, all in all.

Comment: Thanks! I like a lot this solution. Script has a lot of potential!

Comment: This doesn't work - at least with with the script from bsdutils 1:2.25.2-6 on debian. "ls -l" gives colour. "script -q -c 'ls -l'" does not.

Comment: @Draemon: Maybe aliases don't work in the script's shell?

Comment: the brew version of script does not have the -c operator.

Comment: For Mac OSX: `script -q filename.txt vagrant up` works.
`usage: script [-adkpqr] [-t time] [file [command ...]]`

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but this prepends `Script started on Blah blah blah...` to the file even with the `-q` flag.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Apparently you cannot get rid of that header, @AaronN.Brock . :( Please see https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/7ba1ca0d05bd35754e78b22ee470c9828b179c11 for the reason.

Comment: ...or you can, after all, @AaronN.Brock! Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887597/2693875).

Answer (score 14):

You can save the ANSI sequences that colourise your output to a file:

```
echo a | grep --color=always . > colour.txt
cat colour.txt
```

Some programs, though, tend **not to** use them if their output doesn't go to the terminal (that's why I had to use `--color-always` with `grep`).

Comment: do you know if there's a way to do this with `tee`?

Comment: @AAlvz: What happened when you tried? `echo a | grep --color=always . | tee colour.txt`

Comment: It's always red no matter what =/

Comment: @AAlvz: Sure, that's how `grep` is configured by default. I though that was your question: how to get colour into a file. If you want to know how to colourise output, it's a different question.

Comment: Well, the Output of vagrant comes with colors. I just want to see the same colors in the outputfile. Is it possible?

Comment: @AAlvz: Well, the Output of `grep` in my example comes with colours, and you were able to see the same colours in the outputfile. Now, you just have to investigate whether there is an option to vagrant similar to `--color=always`, if it's sensitive to terminal/file output.

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu, you can install the package `bsdutils` to output to a **text file with ANSI color codes**:

```
script -q -c "ls --color=always" /tmp/t
```

Install `kbtin` to generate a clean **HTML** file:

```
ls --color=always | ansi2html > /tmp/t.html
```

Install `aha` and `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a nice **PDF**:

```
ls --color=always | aha | wkhtmltopdf - /tmp/t.pdf
```

Use any of the above with `tee` to display the output also on the console or to save a copy in another file. Example:

```
ls --color=always | tee /dev/stderr | aha | wkhtmltopdf - /tmp/test.pdf
```

Comment: In the RedHat/Rocky/CentOS world, script is usually already installed, from the package util-linux. The ansi2html utility is not available anywhere, but an apparently equivalent utility is ansifilter, which comes from the ansifilter RPM. It can generate various output formats, including LaTeX, which can then be processed into a PDF.

Comment: This plus `catimg` just made for a really fun half hour. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can also color your output with echo with different colours and save the coloured output in file. Example

```
echo -e '\E[37;44m'"Hello World" > my_file
```

Also You would have to be acquainted with the terminal colour codes

**Using tee**

```
< command line > |tee -a 'my_colour_file'
```

Open your file in cat

```
cat 'my_colour_file'
```

Using a named pipe can also work to redirect all output from the pipe with colors to another file

for example

Create a named pipe

```
mkfifo pipe.fifo
```

each command line redirect it to the pipe as follows

```
<command line> > pipe.fifo
```

In another terminal redirect all messages from the pipe to your file

```
cat pipe.fifo > 'my_log_file_with_colours'
```

open your file with cat and see the expected results.

Comment: The problem here is that the Vagrant output has colors already... I'm currently using `tee` to save them to a file

Comment: good observation..nevertheless, it still demonstrates the principle that coloured output can be saved. Answer edited to correct this minor detail.

Comment: I'm also sure that it can be done... But I still don't know how. If you come with an idea, please tell me.

Comment: Okay I edited my answer to demonstrate another of way using named pipes to redirect all coloured output for each command line to a named pipe

Comment: I was so confident that this would work but it doesn't :/ (no colors)

Comment: OK..it is working on my side..However to make this a little more easier try the "tee" command. I further edited my answer to include how to use tee without creating named pipes

Comment: note:for every command you will have to pipe the output to tee, which will append the lines to the file

Answer (score 6):

I found out that using the tool called **[ansi2html.sh](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh)**

Is the most simple way to export colorful terminal data to html file,

The commands to use it are:

```
ls --color=always | ansi2html.sh --palette=solarized > ~/Desktop/ls.html
```

- All is needed is to send the output using a pipe and then output the stdout to simple html file

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

```sh
$ script -q /dev/null -c "your command" > log.txt
$ cat log.txt
```

## Explanation

According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) of `script`, the `--quit` option only makes sure to `be quiet (do not write start and done messages to standard output)`. Which means that the start and done messages will **always** be written to the file.

In order to utilize script and discard the output file at the same file, we can simply specify the null device `/dev/null` to it! Also, redirect the output to our desired destination and the color content will be written to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying out some of the solutions listed here, and I also realized you could do it with the *echo* command and the *-e* flag.

```
$ echo -e "\e[1;33m This is yellow text \e[0m" > sample.txt
```

Next, we can view the contents of our sample.txt file.

```
$ cat sample.txt
```

[Click link to see the output in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbL0H.png)

Additionally, we can also use tee and pipe it with our echo command:

```
echo -e "\e[1;33m This is yellow text \e[0m" | tee -a sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In the RedHat/Rocky/CentOS family, the ansi2html utility does not seem to be available (except for Fedora 32 and up). An equivalent utility is ansifilter from the EPEL repository. Unfortunately, it seems to have been removed from EPEL 8.

script is preinstalled from the util-linux package.

To set up:

```
yum install ansifilter -y
```

To use it:

```
ls --color=always | ansifilter -H > output.html
```

To generate a pretty PDF (not tested), have ansifilter generate LaTeX output, and then post-process it:

```
ls --color=always | ansifilter -L | pdflatex >output.pdf
```

Obviously, combine this with the script utility, or whatever else may be appropriate in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, `script` is from the BSD codebase and you can use it like so:

`script -q /dev/null mvn dependency:tree mvn-tree.colours.txt`

It will run `mvn dependency:tree` and store the coloured output into mvn-tree.colours.txt

The `tee` utility supports colours, so you can pipe it to see the command progress:

`script -q /dev/null mvn dependency:tree | tee mvn-tree.colours.txt`

To get the `script` manual you can type `man script`:

```
SCRIPT(1)                 BSD General Commands Manual                SCRIPT(1)

NAME
     script -- make typescript of terminal session

SYNOPSIS
     script [-adkpqr] [-F pipe] [-t time] [file [command ...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me on MacOS was with using `script` as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SILENT_LOG=/tmp/silent_log_$$.txt
trap "/bin/rm -f $SILENT_LOG" EXIT

function silent {
    script -q $SILENT_LOG $* > /dev/null;
    cat "${SILENT_LOG}";
}

silent npm run lint
```

The `-q` prevents `script` from writing the start and end messages to the file. It seems `script` can only take a single command, so writing it as a function works best as shown above.