# PowerShell output with color redirected to file

Tags: powershell

## `dir` color output to file

If I run the following command on Ubuntu:

```
dharmatech@dharmatech-01:/tmp$ pwsh -Command 'dir' > out.txt
```

and then cat the output:

```
dharmatech@dharmatech-01:/tmp$ cat out.txt
```

the colors are rendered:

[image]

The colors are represented in `out.txt` as escape codes:

[image]

## Write-Host colors

Here I'm using `Write-Host` to display text in red:

[image]

However, if I redirect output to a file, we can see that this time the colors are not represented in the resulting file:

[image]

## Question

Is there a way to get the colors in the file in the `Write-Host` case as they are with the `dir` command?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using the `script` command from bsdutils:

[image]

This is based on this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27399198/268581

## Use case

As an aside, by combining this approach with `terminal-to-html`:

> https://github.com/buildkite/terminal-to-html

I'm able to render arbitrary colored PowerShell output as HTML.

Here's a screenshot which renders output from this PowerShell script as HTML:

> https://github.com/dharmatech/net-liquidity.ps1

[image]

Comment: So is this your answer, or are you still looking?

Comment: @Pieterjan This will only work where `script` is available. So if there's a more portable way to do this, I'd be interested!

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible since Powershell 7.2, as [it has support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.3) for ANSI colors. Credit for this goes to an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75991713/503046).

As for an example (Powershell 7.3.3. / MacOS, YMMV):

```
$PsStyle.OutputRending = "Ansi"
$s = Get-ChildItem | Select -First 3 | Out-String
Set-Content -path foo.txt $s
Get-Content ./foo.txt # prints out colored output
```

Examining the file with, say, `vi` displays the Ansi color codes:

```
...
^[[32;1mUnixMode   User     Group     LastWriteTime    Size   Name^[[0m
^[[32;1m--------   -        -----     -------------    ----   ----^[[0m
...
```

Comment: Hey @vonPryz ‍♂️ Can you get that to work using `Write-Host 'abc' -ForegroundColor Red`?

Comment: @dharmatech What do you mean? That `Write-Host` would show the ANSI control codes? Or that what `Write-Host` writes should also go into a file with colors?

Comment: In your example, you're using `Get-ChildItem`. Can you get your example to work using `Write-Host` as shown above?

Comment: When I try your approach with `Write-Host` instead of `Get-ChildItem`, the red color doesn't appear to show up.

Comment: I.e. see the example case I posted in my question which writes red text: `Write-Host abc -ForegroundColor red`. The escapes don't appear to show up when I use your approach with this example.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) writes [InformationRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.informationrecord) objects to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams#information-stream). This will show if you [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) the information stream to the success stream using `6>&1`:

```
$InformationRecord = Write-Host abc -ForegroundColor Red 6>&1
$InformationRecord | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType         Method     type GetType()
ToString        Method     string ToString()
Computer        Property   string Computer {get;set;}
ManagedThreadId Property   uint ManagedThreadId {get;set;}
MessageData     Property   System.Object MessageData {get;}
NativeThreadId  Property   uint NativeThreadId {get;set;}
ProcessId       Property   uint ProcessId {get;set;}
Source          Property   string Source {get;set;}
Tags            Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[string] Tags {get;}
TimeGenerated   Property   datetime TimeGenerated {get;set;}
User            Property   string User {get;set;}
```

This object holds the color information in the `MessageData` property and doesn't include any ANSI control codes by itself:

```
$InformationRecord.MessageData | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.HostInformationMessage

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType         Method     type GetType()
ToString        Method     string ToString()
BackgroundColor Property   System.Nullable[System.ConsoleColor] BackgroundColor {get;set;}
ForegroundColor Property   System.Nullable[System.ConsoleColor] ForegroundColor {get;set;}
Message         Property   string Message {get;set;}
NoNewLine       Property   System.Nullable[bool] NoNewLine {get;set;}
```

In other words, I don't think that there is any way to preserve the ANSI control code from`Write-Host`. See also: [Is there a way to preserve ANSI control codes in PowerShell command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264735/1701026)

You might consider to write your own `Write-Ansi` [proxy command based on `Write-Host`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/) but there is a general disadvantage with using the `Write-Host` command as you can only use a single color for the whole output which requires to make use of the `-NoNewLne` switch and take that in consideration for any proxy command.

#### Alternatives

Instead of a using a limited (not redirectable) command like:

```
Write-Host 'This whole line is red.' -ForegroundColor Red
```

You might consider using the [`$PSStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals#psstyle) object:

```
 "This is $($PSStyle.Foreground.Red)red$($PSStyle.Reset) text" #  > .\out.txt
```

Or, using [MarkDown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown):

```
'Make this *blue* text' > .\out.txt
(Get-Content .\out.txt | ConvertFrom-MarkDown -AsVT100EncodedString).VT100EncodedString
```

[image]

Or even:

```
Set-MarkdownOption -ItalicsForegroundColor '[91m'
('Make this *red* text' | ConvertFrom-MarkDown -AsVT100EncodedString).VT100EncodedString > .\out.txt
Get-Content .\out.txt
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know about `ConvertFrom-MarkDown`. Been mostly on PS 5.1. Starting to use 7.3. Thank you iRon!