# Format-Table, terminal width and file re-direction

Tags: powershell

Here's a simple script:

```
$json = @"
[
  {
    "record_date": "2023-08-10",
    "account_type": "Treasury General Account (TGA)",
    "transaction_type": "Deposits",
    "transaction_catg": "Dept of Agriculture (USDA) - misc",
    "transaction_catg_desc": "null",
    "transaction_today_amt": 5.0,
    "transaction_mtd_amt": 117.0,
    "transaction_fytd_amt": 3151.0,
    "table_nbr": "II",
    "table_name": "Deposits and Withdrawals of Operating Cash",
    "src_line_nbr": "1",
    "record_fiscal_year": "2023",
    "record_fiscal_quarter": "4",
    "record_calendar_year": "2023",
    "record_calendar_quarter": "3",
    "record_calendar_month": "08",
    "record_calendar_day": "10"
  },
  {
    "record_date": "2023-08-10",
    "account_type": "Treasury General Account (TGA)",
    "transaction_type": "Deposits",
    "transaction_catg": "USDA - Commodity Credit Corporation",
    "transaction_catg_desc": "null",
    "transaction_today_amt": 17.0,
    "transaction_mtd_amt": 198.0,
    "transaction_fytd_amt": 6745.0,
    "table_nbr": "II",
    "table_name": "Deposits and Withdrawals of Operating Cash",
    "src_line_nbr": "2",
    "record_fiscal_year": "2023",
    "record_fiscal_quarter": "4",
    "record_calendar_year": "2023",
    "record_calendar_quarter": "3",
    "record_calendar_month": "08",
    "record_calendar_day": "10"
  }
]
"@

$fields = @(
    'record_date'
    'transaction_catg'
    @{ Expression = 'transaction_today_amt'; Format = 'N0'}
    @{ Expression = 'transaction_mtd_amt';   Format = 'N0'}
    @{ Expression = 'transaction_fytd_amt';  Format = 'N0'}
)


$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ft $fields
```

## Normal output

Here's the output when run interactively in a terminal:

[image]

## Redirect to file: truncated output

If we redirect to a file, the table width is truncated:

[image]

## Out-String : not truncated but color lost

If I change the script itself to use `Out-String -Width 300`:

```
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ft $fields | Out-String -Width 300
```

then the table isn't truncated, but we lose the color in the headers:

[image]

The header color isn't so important, but we also lose colors introduced with `PSStyle`.

## Redirect to file: not truncated

The challenge is, can the output be redirected to a file and have the table width not be truncated.

Here's one approach:

```
tmux new-session -d -x 300 bash -c 'script -q -c "pwsh ./format-table-example.ps1" out'
```

[image]

Explanation:

- `tmux` is being used to setup a terminal of width 300.
- `script` is being used to capture the console output and save it to file `out`. It also preserves colors that are specified with `Write-Host`.

One benefit to this approach is that it can be used from `cron` to run a PowerShell script and capture the output to a file. The script can use `Format-Table` and colored output and it will all be captured.

## Question

This appears to work OK. However it's quite convoluted. It also depends on the external utilities `tmux` and `script` which are Linux/UNIX-centric.

Is there another approach which can be implemented without `tmux` and `script`? Just curious if there's a pure-PowerShell approach.

Ultimately, for my purposes, I can go ahead and use this approach if need be. However, if there's a simpler approach, I'd like to consider it.

Comment: Very simple solution: NEVER use format-table when you want to save something to a file. Format-Table is specificly made to show output in the console (and truncates data). Just omit the use of the format commands when saving data to a file and you should be fine.

Comment: @bluuf That's not a bad principle as far as storing data! However, for my use case, I really do want the layout of `Format-Table` in a file, including the colors. See this answer for the use-case if you're curious: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76864602/268581

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `.OutputRendering` property of the [automatic `$PSStyle` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psstyle) to `'Ansi'` to prevent [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) from stripping VT/ANSI sequences from its output:

```
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'Ansi'
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | Format-Table $fields | Out-String -Width 300
```

---

###### Background information:

Lines produced by PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system (whether *implicitly* in CLI calls or explicitly via `Format-*` cmdlet calls) are *normally* limited to the *terminal (console) width*, namely to 1 less than the number of characters that fit on the *current terminal window*'s lines.
If *no terminal* is involved in a call, a *fixed with of 120 characters* is assumed.

- Curiously, as of PowerShell 7.3.6, on *Unix*-like platforms - unlike on Windows - a *fixed width of 80 characters* is assumed when calling from terminals *with stdout redirected*, which sounds like a bug - see [GitHub issue #20110](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20110).

It is also debatable whether the current terminal window should even factor into the maximum line length when the rendering target is a *string* or a *file*.

- See [GitHub issue #15474](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15474) for a suggestion to impose *no* limit by default when using `Out-String` or `Out-File` / `>`.

Answer (score 1):

I forfeit to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s answer which is the proper way to address this. No need to use my workaround.

The following piece of documentation even state it directly

> You should use ANSI mode when redirecting output to a file or the >pipeline that's intended to be executed downstream. This ensures that >the output isn't altered. Using any other mode alters the output by >removing ANSI escape sequences, which may change the execution >behavior.

[about_ansi_terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.3)

Below is my original — now obsolete — answer, which show how you'd do it using regex and `$psObject.Properties` to iterate through the values and replace the escape sequence to their textual representation prior saving

---

You can achieve this by iterating through the values and replacing the actual ANSI escape sequence with its textual representation. Here's how you can do it:

```
foreach ($item in $obj) {
    foreach ($property in $item.PSObject.Properties) {
        $property.Value = $property.Value -replace "`e", '`e'
    }
}
```

This code ensures that the ANSI sequences are saved as text in the file, rather than being interpreted by the console.

**Simple example**

Consider the following two lines, which both produce the text "This is Red" with a red foreground:

```
$ExampleStr = $PsStyle.Foreground.Red + 'This is Red' + $PsStyle.Reset
$ExampleStr = "`e[31mThis is Red`e[0m" 
#Both output "This is Red" with a red Foreground

$ExampleStr -replace "`e",'`e'
#Output "`e[31mThis is Red`e[0m"
```

This approach ensures that when you save the output to a file, the ANSI color information is retained, allowing for accurate reproduction of the original formatting when viewed with an ANSI-compatible viewer.

Note: If the original string already contains the sequence —`e —, the replacement operation in the provided solution may inadvertently alter the original content. Additional logic would be needed to cover this edge case.